# Conditional select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

Consider the following table (snapshot):

[image]

I would like to write a query to select rows from the table for which

- At least 4 out of 7 column values (VAL, EQ, EFF, ..., SY) are not NULL..

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: It's not too difficult, but, have you tried something yourself?

Comment: Well, I have tried to concoct some logic, but I can't figure out how to translate them into query language: maybe check is.na() for each cell, sum over the row, and check if the sum is greater than 4. But I am not sure how to write that as a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing fancy here, just count the number of non-null per row:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE
  IIF(VAL IS NULL, 0, 1) +
  IIF(EQ IS NULL, 0, 1) + 
  IIF(EFF IS NULL, 0, 1) + 
  IIF(SIZE IS NULL, 0, 1) + 
  IIF(FSCR IS NULL, 0, 1) +
  IIF(MSCR IS NULL, 0, 1) + 
  IIF(SY IS NULL, 0, 1) >= 4
```

Just noticed you tagged sql-server-2005. `IIF` is sql server 2012, but you can substitue `CASE WHEN VAL IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`.

Comment: +1 for I now know about `IIF` and the `CASE` method is exactly how I would do it. :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this? Turning your columns into "rows" and use SQL to count not nulls:

```
select *
from Table1 as t
where
    (
        select count(*) from (values
           (t.VAL), (t.EQ), (t.EFF), (t.SIZE), (t.FSCR), (t.MSCR), (t.SY)
        ) as a(val) where a.val is not null
    ) >= 4
```

I like this solution because it's splits data from data processing - after you get this derived "table with values", you can do anithing to it, and it's easy to change logic in the future. You can sum, count, do any aggregates you want. If it was something like `case when t.VAL then ... end + ...,` than you have to change logic many times.

For example, suppose you want to sum all not null elements greater than 2. In this solution you just changing `count` to `sum`, add `where` clause and you done. If it was `iif(Val is null, 0, 1) +`, first you have to think what should be done to this and then change **every** item to, for example, `case when Val > 2 then Val else 0 end`.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21566)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

Since the values are either numeric or `NULL` you can use `ISNUMERIC()` for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ISNUMERIC(VAL)+ISNUMERIC(EQ)+ISNUMERIC(EFF)+ISNUMERIC(SIZE)
     +ISNUMERIC(FSCR)+ISNUMERIC(MSCR)+ISNUMERIC(SY) >= 4
```